# I cannot think about examples for which the nullity of a map would be greater than 1.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I would like some examples for which the nullity of a map would be greater than 1.

Comment: Literally *every* (*linear*) map from an $n$ dimensional space to an $m$ dimensional space where $n>m+1$ has nullity greater than $1$.  This is of course a sufficient condition but is by no means a necessary one.

Comment: @JMoravitz could you please give me an other example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this isn't the most rigorous way to think about it, in some sense the nullity of a linear transformation represents the "information lost" in the mapping.

So consider a linear transformation from 3 dimensional space (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$) to 2 dimensional space (isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$) defined by mapping each vector to it's 2 dimensional projection. Were we to look at this transformation visually, we'd see that each vector has lost its height (or $z$) component, while it's $x$ and $y$ components have been preserved. We've lost 1 dimension of information but preserved 2. This linear transformation has nullity 1, and equivalently it's null-space is spanned by one vector $e_3$.

Now consider a linear transformation from 3 dimensional space (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$) to 1 dimensional space (isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^1$) via vector projection, or 0 dimensional space via the 0 map. In the first case we've lost both the $z$ and $y$ components from each vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and preserved only the $x$ componenent (each vector is mapped to it's 1 dimensional projection, which is a length only), and in the second case we've preserved no information about each vector, they are all mapped to a point at the origin. The respective null spaces are spanned by $\{e_1, e_2\}$ and $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$.

Linear Algebra thankfully works for many things other than physical space, but I find myself using this sort of physical intuition even more in abstract contexts. I think this is a very valid intuition and way to think about Linear Algebra since all vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic, so given some arbitrary vector space we can think about physical space of that dimension, if it exists. There's an extremely high number of examples of maps with nullity greater than 1, but I hope the 2 physical examples I gave are more valuable for your understanding than the huge number of more abstract examples that exist.

Answer (score 0):

The zero map $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, for any $n\ge 2$.